# Create a list from user input and it should be merge sorted in Prolog

Tags: sorting, split, prolog, mergesort

So my program should ask the user how many numbers to input and after that the user will input the numbers that will sorted and the sorting algorithm should be in **merge sort**.

```
main:-   
   writeln('Number of items? '),
   read(N),
   length(L, N),
   maplist(read, L),    
   mergesort(L, S). 

mergesort([L,B|R],S):-
    split([L, B|R], A1, A2),
    mergesort(A1, S1),
    mergesort(A2, S2),
    format('Sorted list: ~w~n', merge(S1, S2, S)).
    
split([],[],[]).
split([L], [L],[]).
split([L, B|R], [L|Ra], [B|Rb]) :-
    split(R, Ra, Rb).
    
merge(L, [], L).
merge([], B, B).
merge([L|Ra], [B|Rb], [L|M]) :-
    L=< B, 
    merge(Ra, [B|Rb], M).
merge([L|Ra], [L|Rb], [B|M]) :-
    L > B, 
    merge([A|Ra], Rb, M).
```

This is not working it always says **false** after the user inputted the numbers to be sorted.

Comment: Predicate calls cannot be nested, thus ```format('Sorted list: ~w~n', merge(S1, S2, S))``` will not produce the result that you intend.

Comment: i dont understand :(

Comment: The call ```format('Sorted list: ~w~n', merge(S1, S2, S))``` should be write as a conjunction ```merge(S1,S2,S), format('Sorted list: ~w~n',S)```.

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems within your code. First one is a typo in the last rule: you mixed up `A` and `B` and/or `L`. It should be something like this

```
merge([A|Ra], [L|Rb], [L|M]) :-
    L < A, 
    merge([A|Ra], Rb, M).
```

Second mistake is that you never stated when to end the recursive split. I would suggest putting

```
mergesort([A],[A]):-!.
```

before your main `mergesort` rule. The bang (`!`) is called a cut and in this case prevents further backtracking. This shortens the code since you don't have to check within the "main" `mergesort` rule, if your list contains more than one element.

---

Full code; works in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

```
mergesort([A],[A]):-!.
mergesort([L,B|R],S):-
    split([L, B|R], A1, A2),
    mergesort(A1, S1),
    mergesort(A2, S2),
    merge(S1, S2, S).
    
split([],[],[]).
split([L], [L],[]).
split([L, B|R], [L|Ra], [B|Rb]) :-
    split(R, Ra, Rb).
    
merge(L, [], L).
merge([], B, B).
merge([L|Ra], [B|Rb], [L|M]) :-
    L=< B, 
    merge(Ra, [B|Rb], M).
merge([A|Ra], [L|Rb], [L|M]) :-
    L < A, 
    merge([A|Ra], Rb, M).
```

Test case

```
?- mergesort([5,2,4,7,1,0],L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7] ;
false.
```

Works.

Comment: @seungcheol added the full code + test case. Tested in swish (link in the edit)